# Adobe Acrobat and USCIS Form I-485 errors: Enter only letters and spaces

Tags: adobe-acrobat, forms

On [USCIS Form I-485](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-485.pdf), I'm trying to fill out 26.c which pertains to the information on my I-94

> Status on Form I-94 (for example, class of admission or paroled, if paroled)

The answer for my "class of admission" is H1-B. When I try to type in the `1` though I get,

> Enter only letters and spaces

How can I resolve this? I'm using Adobe Acrobat Standard 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods of doing this,

- Get a new reader that you can use to fill in this form,
- Disable JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat

  1. Click `Edit` on the menu
  2. Click `Preferences`
  3. Under `Categories:` on the left, click JavaScript
  4. Uncheck `Enable Acrobat JavaScript`
  5. Click `Ok` to save.

  Interesting **if you want to keep JavaScript on, which is the default and may be needed, you can immediately make the change and save, and then turn it back on.** Everything will work fine.

Comment: These forms are not editable in adobe acrobat.